# Problem on passing array with template in c++

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm new in using template in c++, but there's a problem stuck me recently. I'm writing a simple LU solver in class for CFD which can ideally pass 2 or multiple dimensional array. However the compiler noticed me there's an out-of-line definition happened.
Here's the solver header file:

```
template<size_t N,size_t M>
class Solver{
public:
    Solver();
    void LU_Solver(const double);
```

And it's implementation file:

```
template<size_t N,size_t M>
Solver<N,M>::Solver(){
};
template<size_t N,size_t M>
void Solver<N,M>::LU_Solver(const double (&raw_Mat)[N][M]){
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        while(row < N && column < N){
            double lower_sum = 0;
            double upper_sum = 0;
            for(size_t k=0; k<row; k++){
                lower_sum += Lower_Mat[row][k]*Upper_Mat[k][column];
                upper_sum += Lower_Mat[column][k]*Upper_Mat[k][row];
            }
            Lower_Mat[row][column] = raw_Mat[row][column] - lower_sum;
            Upper_Mat[column][row] = (raw_Mat[column][row]- upper_sum)/Lower_Mat[column][column];
            if(column < row){
                column++;
            }
            else if(column >= row){
                Upper_Mat[column][row] = 1;
                column = 0;
                row++;
            }
        }
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5iiG.png)

The problem appears in the LU_Solver and I have google it but without a precise solution. I want to ask how can I fix this problem or is there has another way to pass undetermined size array, appreciate?

Comment: Note you cannot have template implementation in a separate .cpp file.  see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl

What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post text as text

Answer (score 1):

The parameter list in the declaration (`const double`) is different from the parameter list in the definition (`const double (&raw_Mat)[N][M]`), that should be obvious enough.

Change one to match the other.

Comment: Really appreciate for helping!

Answer (score 1):

The declaration `void LU_Solver(const double);` says that the function `LU_Solver` only takes a single `double` value as argument. That's very much different from `const double (&raw_Mat)[N][M]`. You need to make sure that the arguments match in both the declaration and the definition:

```
template<size_t N,size_t M>
class Solver{
public:
    Solver();
    void LU_Solver(const double (&)[N][M]);
```